# Use DB Relation To Avoid Redundancy

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have designed an ERD of movies and tv series which is confidential. I can give you an overview of database.

It has more then 20 tables (more tables will be added later) and it is normalized. I have tables like Movie, Actors, Tv Seriers, Director, Producer etc. So these tables will contain most important information and also these tables are connected (by foreign keys and middle tables like MovieActor, MovieDirector etc).

So the scenario is like

1) The standard “starting” database should have Actors, Directors, Producers, Music Composers, Genres, Resolution Types… pre populated and pre defined by the Admin.

2) For every user creating his personal movie collection, he will be starting of his database with all the pre defined data, but if he wants to, he may add further data to his personal database.  These changes will only be affecting his database and not the standard "starting" database (which was defined by Admin).

3) The Admin should have a separate view to add Actors, Directors, Producers… that will become part of the standard "starting" database.  Any further changes done to this database will be available to the users as updates.

***Suggested Solution***

[image: Suggestion]

***Question***

The suggested solution is seems like I have to create new databases all the time for each user which seems not possible. My question is how can I manipulate the suggested solution so that my solution will be effective and possible. I would prefer to handle the situation by using database relations, not by separate storage.

Comment: If I understand your quest correctly: In the simplest form, all you need is to add one extra table pairing userid with artifactid -- artifact being whatever you have, actors, movies, etc.  For example `A1203` for Actor 1203, `M5423` for Movie 5423, and so on.  This way, you can also support multiple users adding the same non-default artifact without repetitions.  You can also use -A1203 to exclude artifacts (e.g. delete Actor 1203) from the default database when a user wants to 'delete' items from that list.  Then, it's just a matter of appropriate joins using `UNION` and/or `EXCEPT` logic.

Comment: @tonypdmtr you mean to create new tables for each artifact like MovieUser, ActorUser etc or you mean to create new column (say userId) only in each artifact table ?

Comment: No, I mean a single extra table for all cases. Obviously, all IDs will need to be of the same form.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't create multiple databases, you would simply add an ownerId field to all relevant tables - admin would have ownerId = 0, indicating the row is part of the 'starting database' and new admin entries are instantly available to users.

In any output for a user where you want to display the starting data and their own, you would add WHERE (ownerId = 0 or ownerId = userId) to the appropriate query or if they need to see just their own, just ownerId = userId.

Presumably, they would be able to create relationships between their own data or 'starting' data and this approach should still work.

Foreign keys will still work but deleting will delete user data - basically you should only ever add to the starting data, not take away or you will run into problems.